# Do I need an ejector pump or sump pump?

Tags: plumbing, basement, sump-pump

I currently have two different pits in my basement. One is a true sump pump that pumps out ground water. I just replaced this one and it works fine.
The other pit has a sealed cover and is vented up through the roof.  This pump ties into my main sewer line. I have no basement bathrooms or sinks or washing machines. I inspected it and the only collection source for water is the condensation pipe from my furnace nearby which runs into a floor drain right next to the pit.

**If I replace this pump, can I just replace it with a regular sump pump or do I need an ejector sewage pump?** When I look in the pit, there is no waste water.  It is clear water that looks similar to the ground water in the sump pit. Just trying not to overspend on an unnecessary sewage pump if I don’t need it.

Comment: Is the second pit a collector for a Radon fan circuit? It seems odd that it would be there just for the furnace.

Comment: Does the pump need to be replaced? They usually last a very long time, and likely longer with only clear water service. Some LAHJs do require furnace condensate to go into the sewer for treatment, and there's also the possibility that someone after you will add a basement plumbing device using the ejector pit.

Comment: If your main drain is above basement floor level, a finished working sewage pit is an asset to the house.  I recommend you don't skimp on the pump now, even if you don't quite need it.   "Trying not to overspend" is not something that can be answered in an Answer in this forum., and "need" is a bit hard to pin down too.